# Phase 10 - Do I have to lay down as soon as I have the cards?

Tags: phase-10

MUST you lay down your phase as soon as you draw the cards to play the phase?  If you know someone picked up cards from the discard that will be able to play on your phase and go out do the rules allow you to hang onto the cards until you can lay down and potentially go out all in the same hand?  Of course the risk being that the ofher player goes out anyways and you are stuck with all of your cards and don’t move forward.

Judging by the context and language used in the rules there are many places that say a player MUST do something but in this instance it says a player “may” which leads me to believe holding onto the cards is allowable.

Comment: As to the question of if you can wait, yes.  To the question of if you should, probably not.  In my experience there is more often than not only one player who finishes the 10th phase and it rarely comes down to points.

Answer (score 2):

No you are not need to go down if you have your phase in your hand.

Taken from the rules:
MAKING A PHASE: If, during your turn, you are able to make a Phase with the cards in
your hand, lay the Phase down, face-up on the table before discarding. For example,
you are trying to make Phase 1. You have 3 “5s” and 2 “7s” and you draw another “7.”
You now have 2 sets of 3, and you may lay them down. In the next hand, you will be
working on Phase 2.

They say that you may lay them down so I would say you can wait as long as you want to laid down your phase.
Link to the rules: http://www.tactic.net/site/rules/FIN/03140.pdf